# Return distinct items in asp-mvc4 list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, distinct

How would I return a unique list 'listColl' I tried using 'Distinct9' at the bottom with 'return listColl;' but received an error.but it didnt work. Currently this return a duplicate list of items which populates a treeview coded in query.

```
        public List<SPList> GetAllLibraries(string webURL)
    {
        var listColl = new List<SPList>();
        ClientContext _ctx = new ClientContext(webURL);
        try
        {
            var currentWeb = _ctx.Web;
            var AllLists = currentWeb.Lists;
            _ctx.Load(AllLists);
            _ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            var query = from list in currentWeb.Lists
                        where list.BaseType == BaseType.DocumentLibrary
                        select list;

            var listCollection = _ctx.LoadQuery(query.Include(myList => myList.Title,
                                          myList => myList.Id,
                                          myList => myList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                          myList => myList.ParentWebUrl,
                                          myList => myList.Hidden,
                                          myList => myList.IsApplicationList));
            _ctx.ExecuteQuery();

          //   /*
            listColl.AddRange(from list in listCollection
                              where !list.Hidden
                              select new SPList
                              {
                                  Title = list.Title,
                                  ListGUID = list.Id.ToString(),
                                  RootFolderServerRelativeUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                  ParentWebUrl = list.ParentWebUrl
                              });
       // } */
            foreach (var Item in listCollection)
            {
                listColl.Add(new SPList
                {
                    Title = Item.Title,
                    RootFolderServerRelativeUrl = Item.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                    ListGUID = Item.Id.ToString()
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // error log
            string error = ex.Message + " Error within GetAllLibraries ";
        }
        return listColl;
    }
```

Comment: The below answers did not produce any error nor did they fix the problem. Could it perhaps be that the default equality parameter of Distinct needs to be overridden?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
  return listColl.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listColl.AddRange((from list in listCollection
                          where !list.Hidden
                          select new SPList
                          {
                              Title = list.Title,
                              ListGUID = list.Id.ToString(),
                              RootFolderServerRelativeUrl = list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                              ParentWebUrl = list.ParentWebUrl
                          }).Distinct());
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix solved the problem in the mean time. The reason I can no do Distinct() is because of SPList.

```
    List<SPList> distinct = new List<SPList>();
    List<String> ids = new List<string>();
    foreach (var lst in listColl)
    {
        if (!ids.Contains(lst.ListGUID))
        {
            distinct.Add(lst);
            ids.Add(lst.ListGUID);
        }
    }
return distinct;
```